# How to convert this code from Unityscript to C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, code-conversion

I am trying to convert Unity UnityScript to C#. I am getting this error:

> Assets/Scripts/BoostPlatformCheck.cs(40,36): error CS0019: Operator
>   `==' cannot be applied to operands of type`int' and `object'

Here is the C# code:

```
int collidedWith = collisionInfo.gameObject.GHetInstanceID();  
ArrayList collided = new ArrayList();

....

     if(collidedWith == collided[collided.Count - i - 1])
            {
                alreadyExists = true;
                return; 
            }
```

I changed Array to ArrayList and collided.length to collided.Count when I converted it from JS to C#.

Comment: Try:　`if(collidedWith ==Convert.ToInt32(collided[collided.Count - i - 1]))`

Comment: What is stored in your `ArrayList`? If they're all the same thing - which it appears they are; `int`s - then you should be using a `List<int>`.. which will allow your comparison. Also, **don't do what Tim said to do above this comment**.

Comment: I am shocked that Tim's comment has an upvote - its 2014 people - we have strongly typed containers for this. You shouldn't be casting objects from an `ArrayList` from .NET 2 and onward. Certainly not in this simple instance anyway.

Comment: also it's UnityScript, not JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I changed Array to ArrayList and collided.length to collided.Count
>   when I converted it from JS to C#

Since you just want to convert the code to C#, use array of int instead of ArrayList:

```
int[] collided = new int [10]; // This is how you declare arrays in C#
```

Then you can just use `collided.length` like in Javascript to find the length of the array.

Also one more thing, arrays in C# has a built in function `Contains()` that may help you in your case, which seems like you're iterating over the array to compare `collidedWith`. To simplify, you can remove the loop and try this:

```
// This means collidedWith exists within collided, so you won't need the loop anymore
if(collided.Contains(collidedWith)) 
    alreadyExists = true;
```